# Transferring all contents of a repository into a directory in another existing repository

Tags: git, mv, github

I have a GitHub repository (X) and I want to move all its files into a directory in another existing GitHub repository (Y), just like a regular `mv ${HOME}/x/* ${HOME}/y/x` in a Linux file tree.

- I don't care about the Git history of the files in this particular case, I just want the files per se
- If I create a zip file containing all files of the first repository and upload it to the second repository, currently GitHub doesn't give me an option to **extract** it in the relevant directory

How to move all files in a repository into a directory in another existing repository?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to move it to a new repository or move the contents into an existing repo? If it's the former, just rename the repo under settings and change the remote in any local version of the repo. If it's the latter, do you want to merge two repos and keep their history, just include any files from X in Y or include X as a submodule of Y?

Comment: @frippe it's the latter and about your last clarification question, I want to move only all files in repo X to a submodule (directory) of repo Y.

Comment: @frippe if you think I have addressed your points please consider to delete the comment as I have already edited the question.

Comment: Do you want a submodule, or a directory? They’re not the same: a submodule is a reference from one repo to another.

Comment: @StephenKitt oh, I didn't know --- I want a directory.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in concept of *moving* files between repositories. You can *copy* the files, and separately if you like you can remove them from the old repository.

Suppose you want to move the files from branch `master` of `https://github.com/roiko/x`, into branch `main` of `https://github.com/roiko/y`, and you want to move the files under the directory `subdir`.

Here's a way to move the files and preserve their history. The history will record the files as having been at the root, then moved under `subdir` and “imported”. It's also possible to record the files as having always been under `subdir`, but it requires extra tools. Warning: untested code.

1. Make a working copy with both x and y available as remotes

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/roiko/y
   cd y
   git remote add x https://github.com/roiko/x
   git fetch x
   ```
2. Move the files in the old repository to the subdirectory. I assume that subdir doesn't already exist in `x`. We'll create a temporary local branch `x-move` to do the move. It starts at `x/master` and adds a move commit.

   ```
   git checkout -b x-move x/master
   mkdir subdir
   shopt -s extglob dotglob
   git mv -- !(.git|subdir) subdir/
   git commit -m 'Move everything to subdir/'
   ```

   The `shopt` command is for bash. In zsh, use `setopt kshglob dotglob` instead.
3. Import the moved files into `y`. This means creating a local branch to work on the content of `y`, and merging the `x-move` branch we created in the previous step.

   ```
   git checkout -b main y/main
   git merge x-move
   git commit -m 'Import files from roiko/x under subdir'
   ```
4. Push the result.

   ```
   git push origin
   ```
5. Optionally, remove the `x` repository. All the contents and history of its `master` branch are now recorded in `y`, but other branches, issues, etc. are not.

Comment: I thank you dearly Gilles for all your time in trying to help me; I as a non git user find this an "overkill" for my case specifically; perhaps if I download a zip file of the files (downloaded from GitHub), upload it to the other repository and then extract it somehow it will be much simpler for me; I first need to figure out how do I SSH into my GitHub account (if that's even possible) and then `unzip`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t care about preserving the history of `x`, here’s how to move it into `y`:

1. Clone both projects

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/roiko/x
   git clone https://github.com/roiko/y
   ```
2. Copy all of `x` into `y`

   ```
   cp -a x y/
   ```
3. Create a commit containing all the copied data

   ```
   cd y
   git add x
   git commit -m "Import files from roiko/x"
   ```
4. Push the updated `y`

   ```
   git push
   ```